# Solution to at least one ODE in a family of ODE's

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis

I have stumbled across the following 1st order complex differential equation for smooth functions $\eta:\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{C}-\lbrace0\rbrace$ defined on the circle,
$$i\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial t}+(re^{it}+\varepsilon i)\bar\eta=0$$
where $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}_+$ is small and *fixed* (so choose $0<\varepsilon<<1$ but maybe not $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$) and $r\in\mathbb{R}_+$ is a nonzero positive real *parameter*. Using some functional analysis and perturbation theory, there must exist a nontrivial solution $\eta\in C^\infty(S^1,\mathbb{C}^\ast)$ to this ODE for *at least one* choice of $r\in\mathbb{R}_+$. **What is such a pair $(r,\eta)$?**

My attempt was to Fourier expand $\eta(t)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}a_ke^{ikt}$ and obtain the recurrence relation $-ka_k+r\bar a_{1-k}+\varepsilon i\bar a_{-k}=0$. I need a specific collection $\lbrace a_k\rbrace\subset\mathbb{C}$ which solves this (for some $r>0$), but I get stuck. What we get at the least is $r=\varepsilon i\frac{a_0}{a_1}$ (and subsequently $\frac{a_0}{a_1}$ must be purely complex and nonzero). But there is still a good chance that the coefficients $a_k$ will "blow up" as $k\to\infty$ if not chosen carefully.

Also, this *complex* ODE is equivalent to two coupled *real* ODEs, but I don't think it helps. Decompose $\eta=x+iy$ and attempt to solve the equivalent system:
$$\dot y(t) -r\cdot\cos(t)\cdot x(t) -[\varepsilon +r\cdot\sin(t)]\cdot y(t) = 0$$
$$\dot x(t) -r\cdot\cos(t)\cdot y(t) +[\varepsilon +r\cdot\sin(t)]\cdot x(t) = 0$$
Perhaps there are numerical methods to find "approximate" periodic solutions, or some software to plot $(x,y)$ for various values of $r\in\mathbb{R}_+$?

Comment: Please note that I know very few about complex analysis, but I wonder if you naively can treat it as a real ODE. In fact, it is linear, thus separable.

Comment: But there is nontrivial "mixing." It may be amenable to techniques in applied math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One month later, this question has been re-posted and answered satisfactorily here:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280825/solution-to-at-least-one-ode-in-a-family-of-odes

Answer (score 0):

Replace $k$ with $1-k$ to obtain a second relation on the $\pm k,\pm(k-1)$ coefficient set
\begin{align}
0&=-ka_k+r\bar a_{1−k}+iε\bar a_{−k}\\
0&=(k-1)\bar a_{1-k}+r a_k-iε a_{k-1}
\\
\implies
0&=(r^2+k(k-1))\bar a_{1−k}+iε\bar a_{−k}-iε a_{k-1}
\end{align}
which allows to get the $\pm k$ coefficients from the $\pm(k-1)$ coefficients as
\begin{align}
a_k&=\frac1r\Bigl(iε a_{k-1}-(k-1)\bar a_{1-k}\Bigr)
\\
\bar a_{-k}&=\frac1{iε}\Bigl(iε a_{k-1}-(r^2+k(k-1))\bar a_{1−k}\Bigr)
\end{align}
It seems impossible to get a non-trivial finite or stable infinite solution.

Comment: I was also able to get various relations amongst the coefficients, but it got too complicated to predicate the next coefficient: We are iteratively subtracting coefficients and flipping their real/imaginary parts via multiplication by $i$, and $\varepsilon$ is small but exists in both numerators and denominators. I cannot parse whether these facts are helpful or harmful.

Comment: Now, we do have freedom in choosing $a_0$ and $a_1$ (subject to their quotient being imaginary), and this subsequently determines $r$. So I can imagine the magnitude of the coefficients decreasing super-exponentially fast (hopefully) if we make the right choices.